# Nodejs GET request to mongoDB returns undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, get

backend

```
const GetUsersRoute = express.Router();
const GetContactUsers = require('./DB/GetContactUsers');

app.get('/fetchContactUsers', (req, res) => {
    GetContactUsers.find({}, (err, user) => { 
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.json(err);
        } else {
            console.log(user.data);
            res.json(user.data);
        }
    });
});
```

./DB/GetContactUsers

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const GetContactUsers = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    message: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('GetContactUsers', GetContactUsers);
```

I'm doing the request via Postman and it returns undefined. DB is connected, POST request work with no problems. What am I missing?

Comment: `console.log(user);` it's array of records. You can do `user[0].data`

Comment: This returns "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined"

Comment: What does `console.log(user)` prints ?

Comment: Returns an empty array

Comment: There are no records in the database.

Comment: I thought the same, but I have 1 database (where I make the post requests too) with 2 collections, both populated

Answer (score 0):

use this way ...

```
GetContactUsers.find({}.then(function (doc) {
  // use doc
}).catch(ex){

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this and also confirm that there exists Object with named "Data" in your user model

```
    app.get('/fetchContactUsers', async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const allContactUsers = await GetContactUsers.find();
        console.log(allContactUsers);     //chech if User have Object Data
        res.status(201).json(allContactUsers.data);  //if still undefined than there may be no object with "DATA"
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It returns an empty array. What should I change?

Comment: If empty, than first you need add Data in the database and than fetch that data. Also mark the answer "ticked" if helped.